# retiving data from fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

The JSON placeholder API gives me the data but open weather API gives error and the error is 'Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data'
Whats going wrong? and how I can read the weather API data?

```
      fetch(
        // 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'
        'api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=bhubneshwar&appid=2f5e9a7699ace605d4cbf50f813d7b0b'
      )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => console.log(data));
```

Comment: A simple check in the dev tools to check what has gone wrong with the request, would reveal the problem.

Comment: fetching with https returns city not found

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP protocol is missing from the URL & besides that city name isn't right on your URL. Use that instead:

```
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=bhubaneswar&appid=2f5e9a7699ace605d4cbf50f813d7b0b
```

Full code:

```
fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=bhubaneswar&appid=2f5e9a7699ace605d4cbf50f813d7b0b')
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .then((data) => console.log(data));
```

Comment: OK, Sorry. I will keep that in mind in the future. @gre_gor

Comment: Wrong city name has nothing to do with, not returning valid JSON.

Comment: Yes, HTTP protocol was missing too on the URL.